# How Facebook notification works on Google Chrome of Android phone

Tags: html, google-chrome, notifications

I have built a Web application which use the notification of the browser, anyway when I close or put chrome in background I got no notifications.

I was wondering how Facebook push notifications on Google Chrome even if Facebook.com closed or chrome in background I almost get fb notification instantly.

I would like for my Web app to have the same capability, any suggestions are welcome.

Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no short answer to this question but I will show you where you should search for your answer.

[Push API](http://w3c.github.io/push-api/)

[Notifications API](https://notifications.spec.whatwg.org/)

[Google Dev - Your First Push Notifications Web App](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/push-notifications/?hl=en)